# Restore 20TB Harddrive after installing 2GB Operating System

Tags: windows, partitioning, data-recovery, fedora

Here's what happened:
I ran the Fedora Media Write from here (https://fedoraproject.org/fmw/FedoraMediaWriter-win32-latest.exe) and selected my hard-drive, not by accident there was just no warning it would format and shamelessly overwrite my partition tables - I thought it would install it like a program.
Now I can recover like 99,99% of my data with Data Recovery Tools like DiskGenius V5.5.1.1508 but I don't have a drive that can hold the data.
Is there a way I can only "re-make" the partition table in the beginning so windows starts to recognize the folders and files in there again? Basically if I only put a partition table on the first 2GB of the hard-drive - is there a way to achieve that so I don't need to copy multiple Terabytes of Data which seem to be just fine on the hard-drive as of now?

I already tried to just assign the Drive a letter through Windows hard-drive control center, it wouldn't recognize the filesystem (obviously cuz it was overwritten), I fear if I format it with NTFS (which was on the drive before) it will not recognize the other data, is there software that can write a partition table(i hope that's the right term, I'm just assuming its whatever happens when you partition a drive)?

here's a screenshot on how the Drive looks like in windows hard-drive control software:

[image]

Comment: TestDisk might work but you shouldn’t perform the operation on your only copy

Comment: There is already a partition table for the disk, just that the file-systems have become RAW.

Comment: Sorry to hear you've lost your data. The information about FMW [clearly warns](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/preparing-boot-media/#_fedora_media_writer) that it's for creating boot images, not for installing Fedora on your harddrive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device), specifically https://superuser.com/a/1758086/705502